# Javascript "implicit" condition in IF statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is so basic that it may well already exist somewhere here.  Apologies for not having found it - my knowledge of coding lingo must be too limited to be an effective searcher...

I have seen several instances of code where a condition does not have an equal sign.  For example:

```
var test = true;
if (test){
   console.log("success");
} else {
   console.log("failure");
}
```

outputs `success` whereas if `var test = false`, the output would be `failure`.

What exactly is the implicit condition (e.g., `== true` vs `=== true`)?  And what is the full set of values for `test` that would output `failure`?  It is just `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`?

Comment: The key words to search for are `truthy` and `falsey`.  Any expression that evaluates to `truthy` will satisfy an `if` in Javascript.  Lots of different values are `truthy`,  not just `true`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks - totally covers it. just didn't know the terms...